# traceroute outputs only * * *

Tags: networking, ubuntu-10.10, traceroute

Am trying to traceroute to google.com but unfortunately this is the output I am getting -

[image: output to traceroute]

I know that these `* * *`s mean that the packets are not reaching back, perhaps due to firewalls, but no matter which website I am trying to traceroute, I am getting the same output, even our internal website. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the "10.144.1.1" is your local network gateway, and since traceroute relys on ICMP packets to function, I think the most probable reason is ICMP packets are not allowed through your gateway.

Comment: Ya 10.144.1.1 is my local network gateway, but my other friends can get a trace, I don't know how.